# Magento 1.8.1.0 - SUPEE-7405 - Ajax call redirects to dashboard on non-admin accounts

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I just installed SUPEE-7405 patch on a Magento 1.8.1.0.

After logging on a non-admin account, i edit a cart rule
(Promotions > Cart Rule)

In the third tab (Actions), i add a new condition (Category), upon clicking on the three dots, i click on the window-like button on the right of the textbox (the one that is supposed to show you a list of categories).

It's an ajax call to "/promo_widget/chooser/attribute/category_ids/form/rule_actions_fieldset/key/40c88f1400c874b61b75c5388b43af9f/?isAjax=true"

The ajax call throws a 403 (forbidden) and then the page redirects to the dashboard.

After checking all the files that got modified by the patch, i can't figure out what is going wrong.

This works fine on an admin account, so maybe it's an ACL issue but the rights are fine on the user role, and it worked before the patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in connection with restricted admin roles / ACL rules.

File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/WidgetController.php

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('promo/catalog');
}
```

If you have only "Shopping cart price rules" enabled for the admin user and not "Catalog price rules" then the bug can happen when a widget is used (like the category widget in "actions"-tab.

There are two possibilities to solve this:

1. Give the admin role access to catalog price rules too
2. Overwrite the method "is_Allowed()" by:

`protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('promo/catalog') || Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('promo/quote');
    }`

Comment: I'm gonna try this and give you feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: You figured out the problem. I tested both of your solutions, but i'll stick to the first one, we don't mind our user having access to both shopping cart price rules and catalog price rules.

It's not the first time Magento oversees something in their ACL management.

Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install previous Magento SUPEE patches patch first (particularly SUPEE-6788), because:

> It's an ajax call to "/promo_widget/chooser..."

This form of admin routing is deprecated and SUPEE-6788 would replace it with something like "/index.php/admin/promo_widget/chooser...".

> This works fine on an admin account, so maybe it's an ACL issue but the rights are fine on the user role, and it worked before the patch.

SUPEE-6788 also changes the default permission level in admin from "allow all" to "deny all" unless explicitly defined in your admin controllers.

This change means that "super-admin" role users will *always* be allowed to access any admin page, because the role says "Allow All" as a high level flag, whereas other roles may have individual ACL settings and have previously relied on the ACLs not specifically set to be "allow" rather than "deny." In this case, a 403 permission denied error is expected.

You can fix this (if it's a custom module) by adding the following method to your module's admin controllers:

```
/**
 * Check is allowed access to action
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('your/acl/path');
}
```

---

Another possibility for your 403 Permission Denied error is that since it's an AJAX request, you may need to ensure that the *form key* is added to the AJAX request. If this is the case, it's likely that you've modified the core template or overridden it with a local theme version. If *that* is the case, go through and compare your version of the template against the core version and copy through any changes from the patch.

---

[Installing SUPEE-6788 is a pain in the a**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87214/how-to-check-which-modules-are-affected-by-security-patch-supee-6788) if you have custom modules that have to be updated, but generally speaking the recommendation is to install all previous security patches before you install new ones.

A useful resource is the Magento StackExchange's reference for SUPEE-7405 changes, and which files are affected - [see here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems).

Comment: SUPEE-6788 already installed before applying SUPEE-7405.

All the _isAllowed are added where it should.

I just tested this behaviour on another site we have on 1.8.1.0 where the patch have been deployed, and it's working fine.
I think the problem lies with a rewrite somewhere in a app/code/local/Mage file, i'm gonna figure it out.

Thanks for your help though.